# connecting visual studio 2010 to assembla SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, assembla

I'm working now with a friend on creating a project together and a SVN is quite needed.

however, yesterday when I tried to save my Project to Assembla I couldn't manage to commit it correctly.
in the beginning, I thought it might be due to me using a live login from google ID. so I created a new user using a normal user name and password. but it just didn't help.

Visual Studio 2010 opens the login dialog for connecting to Assembla and asked for my username and password, I entered them but received an error message saying that the response code from the server was a 400 one...

looking all over the web, I couldn't find an explanation on how to do this.

any thoughts?

Comment: "I couldn't manage to save it correctly" - details please. What does that mean _exactly_?

Comment: "Visual Studio 2010 opens the login dialog for connecting to Assembla and asked for my username and password, I entered them but received an error message saying that the response code from the server was a 400 one"      later on today, I'll post a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have anything against Assembla but *I think its a very bad idea* to try and integrate mercurial / git to Visual Studio. If you do not have TFS integrated with Visual Studio, you are much better off using a stand alone Mercurial client than trying to integrate one to your Visual Studio.

We have been using bitbucket.org by Atlassian for hosting small projects for collaboration. They have a free plan to collaborate up to five users with private repositories.

Manual steps involved in using Visual Studio with Mercurial

1. Create an account at bitbucket.org
2. Download a mercurial client like [TortoiseHg](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+Git+and+Mercurial?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=blank_repo) to your machine
3. Create a repository on bitbucket.org
4. Clone the git repo to your machine.
5. Push changes as your code.

Thats it!. Here is a complete tutorial on using Mercurial / Git using bitbucket.org - [bitbucket101](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+101?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=blank_repo)

P.S: There is no harm in using Assembla if you already have a plan, just make sure you do not install extra scripts into your Visual Studio. TortoiseHg can sure handle any Mercurial.

---

Update based on your comment:

Well yes and no. Microsoft always had its own source control system. Earlier it was Source Safe. Now they have upgraded it to another much better option called [Team Fundation Server (TFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) which among doing many other things, also controls source

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seemed to me like VS2010 has already integrated posting the code on repositories